# Implicit conversion causing long running query

Tags: sql-server

I am somewhat new to tuning and I am getting the following errors/warnings that may be impacting my query performance.  From what little I know I see the query is doing full table scans.

I checked the following IO stats:

```
 Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read- 
 ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead 
 reads 0.
 Table 'STOLOT'. Scan count 1, logical reads 413, physical reads 0, read-ahead 
 reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
 Table 'ITMMASTER'. Scan count 1, logical reads 87, physical reads 0, read- 
 ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead 
 reads 0.
```

The `stolot.Lot_0` column is only a `varchar(15)` in the table. `Itmref`    is an `nvarchar(20)`.  It appears because of the conversion issue it is not seeing the indexes thus it is falling back on a full table scan.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
 <Warnings>
          <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" 
 Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(25),[x3v7].[LIVE].[STOLOT].[LOT_0],0)" 
 />
          <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" 
 Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(max),[x3v7].[LIVE].[ITMMASTER]. 
 [ITMREF_0],0)" />
          <PlanAffectingConvert ConvertIssue="Cardinality Estimate" 
 Expression="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(25),[x3v7].[LIVE].[ITMMASTER]. 
 [TSICOD_3],0)" />
        </Warnings>

     SELECT DISTINCT
     STOLOT.LOT_0
     ,ITMMASTER.ITMREF_0
     ,dbo.fnGetAlpha(GETDATE(), STOLOT.LOT_0, ITMMASTER.ITMREF_0,TSICOD_3)
      FROM
      LIVE.STOLOT
        inner join
      LIVE.ITMMASTER on STOLOT.ITMREF_0 = ITMMASTER.ITMREF_0
      WHERE
      TSICOD_0 = 'HOP01'
      ORDER BY LOT_0
```

Comment: You forgot to include the query in your post. Are you, perhaps, performing a `JOIN` with `tolot.Lot_0 = Itmref` or a `WHERE` where you're comparing `tolot.Lot_0` to an `nvarchar`? If so, there's you're problem; `tolot.Lot_0 ` will be implicitly cast to an `nvarchar` and if that happens the indexes are useless as the query is no longer SARGable.

Comment: If you comment out the scalar function, does it "improve"? And why do you need to use distinct? Usually that is a kludge to cover up a logical query flaw or a schema flaw.